# How to handle cyclic reference with Maven multimodule + ManyToMany jpa

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jpa, many-to-many, multi-module

I've been trying to separate the my API into a multi module springboot application but I've got stuck with cyclic references on a many to many relation that I have between two different entities that are supposed to be in different modules.

first we have the entity Spreadsheet that's inside the module `virtual-mattress-spreadsheet`:

```
@Entity
data class Spreadsheet(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long? = null,
    val title: String,
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    val userList: List<User>
)
```

And it's pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.virtual-mattress</groupId>
        <artifactId>virtual-mattress</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.virtual-mattress</groupId>
    <artifactId>virtual-mattress-spreadsheet</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>virtual-mattress-sheet</name>
    <description>Virtual Mattress sheet module</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.6.10</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.virtual-mattress</groupId>
            <artifactId>virtual-mattress-user</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Then we have the entity user inside the module `virtual-mattress-user`:

```
    @Entity
data class User(
    val id: Long?,
    val name: String,
    val email: String,

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    val type: UserType,
    val password: String,
    
    @ManyToMany
    val sheetList: List<Sheet>
)
```

and it's pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.virtual-mattress</groupId>
        <artifactId>virtual-mattress</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.virtual-mattress</groupId>
    <artifactId>virtual-mattress-user</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>virtual-mattress-user</name>
    <description>Virtual Mattress user module</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.6.10</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.virtual-mattress</groupId>
            <artifactId>virtual-mattress-spreadsheet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The problem is that when i try to build the project I get the following error:

```
org.apache.maven.ProjectCycleException: The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between 'Vertex{label='com.virtual-mattress:virtual-mattress-user:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'}' and 'Vertex{label='com.virtual-mattress:virtual-mattress-spreadsheet:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'}' introduces to cycle in the graph com.virtual-mattress:virtual-mattress-spreadsheet:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT --> com.virtual-mattress:virtual-mattress-user:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT --> com.virtual-mattress:virtual-mattress-sheet:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

And this is how far I've got. I don't know how to handle it since both entities are in different sibling modules and I need to import the other entity in both of them.

I even considered to move my models to a separate common module so I can import it in both with no problems but this seems to much as a work around, there may be a better solution for this.

Hope you are able to help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a JPA, many-to-many or spring issue. How do you compile one of the projects when it requires the 'other' to have already been compiled? You can't. Reworking your projects isn't a hack, it is what you need to do, as these two projects are really just a single one you've mistakenly broken out along invalid lines. Combine them, create a new module for them, or move one of the classes into the other's module.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your comment. So what would you suggest me in this case? Put together the user and and the spreadsheet module or create a new one with my models so I can use them in all my application? What's the best approach?